# Empty SDL2 window taking lots (40%+) GPU to render?

Tags: c++, graphics, sdl-2

I've been trying to learn how to use SDL2, and am trying to follow the tutorials [here](https://lazyfoo.net/tutorials/SDL/index.php#Hello%20SDL) for that. From example 7 (texture loading / hardware rendering), I've put together this stripped down example. As far as I can tell, the code is only calling `SDL_RenderClear()` and `SDL_RenderPresent()` in the render loop, VSYNC'd to my monitor (100 Hz in this case). However, I'm seeing Windows report 40% GPU utilization when doing this, which seems high for doing nothing. My GPU sits at 1-2% utilization when the SDL2 program is not running.

Removing just the `SDL_RenderPresent()` call brings the usage all the way down to 1-2% again, but then nothing gets drawn, which makes me think that the issue is either in SDL2's rendering, or (much more likely), how I've configured it.

Is this high GPU utilization (when doing nothing) expected? Is there anything I can do to minimize the GPU utilization (while still using hardware rendering)?

===================================

#### Machine details:

- Windows 10
- Threadripper 3970x CPU (3.7 GHz 32 core)
- 256 GB RAM DDR4 3200 MHz
- 1x RTX 3090 GPU
- 3x 1440p 100Hz monitors

#### GPU utilization (shown via Task Manager and Xbox Game Bar):

[image]

#### Code:

```
#define SDL_MAIN_HANDLED

/*This source code copyrighted by Lazy Foo' Productions (2004-2020)
and may not be redistributed without written permission.*/

// Using SDL, SDL_image, standard IO, and strings
#include <SDL.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>

// Screen dimension constants
const int SCREEN_WIDTH = 1920;
const int SCREEN_HEIGHT = 1080;

// Starts up SDL and creates window
bool init();

// Frees media and shuts down SDL
void close();

// The window we'll be rendering to
SDL_Window* gWindow = NULL;

// The window renderer
SDL_Renderer* gRenderer = NULL;

bool init() {
  // Initialization flag
  bool success = true;

  // Initialize SDL
  if (SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO) < 0) {
    printf("SDL could not initialize! SDL Error: %s\n", SDL_GetError());
    success = false;
  } else {
    // Create window
    gWindow = SDL_CreateWindow(
        "SDL Tutorial",
        SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED,
        SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED,
        SCREEN_WIDTH,
        SCREEN_HEIGHT,
        SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN);
    if (gWindow == NULL) {
      printf("Window could not be created! SDL Error: %s\n", SDL_GetError());
      success = false;
    } else {
      // Create renderer for window
      gRenderer =
          SDL_CreateRenderer(gWindow, -1, SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED | SDL_RENDERER_PRESENTVSYNC);
      if (gRenderer == NULL) {
        printf("Renderer could not be created! SDL Error: %s\n", SDL_GetError());
        success = false;
      } else {
        // Initialize renderer color
        SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(gRenderer, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00);
      }
    }
  }

  return success;
}

void close() {
  // Destroy window
  SDL_DestroyRenderer(gRenderer);
  SDL_DestroyWindow(gWindow);
  gWindow = NULL;
  gRenderer = NULL;

  // Quit SDL subsystems
  SDL_Quit();
}

int main(int argc, char* args[]) {
  // Start up SDL and create window
  if (!init()) {
    printf("Failed to initialize!\n");
  } else {
    // Main loop flag
    bool quit = false;

    // Event handler
    SDL_Event e;

    // While application is running
    while (!quit) {
      // Handle events on queue
      while (SDL_PollEvent(&e) != 0) {
        // User requests quit
        if (e.type == SDL_QUIT) {
          quit = true;
        }
      }

      // Clear screen
      SDL_RenderClear(gRenderer);

      //Update screen
      SDL_RenderPresent( gRenderer );
    }
  }

  // Free resources and close SDL
  close();

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Writing to ~830 MiB of VRAM every second is a bit more than "doing nothing" :)

Comment: I just tried removing the `SDL_RenderClear()` call, keeping only the `SDL_RenderPresent()` call, which should remove the internal framebuffer getting overwritten, but even that still takes the same 40% or so GPU to run. I wonder what else could be causing the slowdown?

Comment: I've had `SDL_RenderPresent` waste 100% cpu while waiting to render, when vsync is enabled. (Actually, it was `SDL_GL_SwapWindow`, but it should be the same thing.) Try predicting how long `SDL_RenderPresent` is going to wait, then sleep, say, 1ms less before calling it.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat OP's complaining about GPU usage; their CPU usage is 1%.